# Octave: resize figure with subplots

Tags: plot, octave

I have a simple question about subplots.
If I write:

```
x=linspace(0,50,4);
subplot(1,2,1);
plot(x,x.^2);
subplot(1,2,2);
plot(x,x.^4);
```

I get two very tall and narrow plots in a quadratic window.
How to change the size of the window that I have two plots of quadratic size
in a rectangular window whose height is half the width?
I know how to resize the subplots in the figure window to quadratic plots, but then above them is half the figure empty, and I don't want this.

I asked this also on help@octave.org, but didn't get an answer till now.

Comment: What do you men by "quadratic window" or "quadratic size"? Have you tried calling `axis` with the `"equal"` argument (https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.1/Axis-Configuration.html)? Or do you maybe want `subplot(2,1,1)` and `subplot(2,1,2)` instead?

Comment: @Dan, if I run the script, I get two subplots left and right for each height:width is 2:1. I can resize the subplots such that they have the dimensions 1:1 and are in the lower part of the figure window, but then the upper part is empty. How to get a figure window, so that it is filled by the subplots, i.e. whose  dimensions are 1:2?

Comment: Did you try my suggestions above? `subplot(2,1,1)` should do it. i.e. you are telling `subplot` you want two rows and one column of charts (i.e. two charts vertically stacked) instead of what you current have which is one row two columns.

Comment: @Dan, if I do what you suggested, I got two plots above each other (which I don't want, I want one to the left and one to the right) and both have now a ratio 1:2. I want two plots with ratio 1:1 which *fill* the figure window. So the problem as I see it: how to resize the figure window?

Comment: so then did you try my first suggestion of calling `axis` with `"equal"` ? Or you might want `"square"` instead of equal if you on;y care about aspect ration and not about keeping the units of the two axes the same.

Comment: @Dan, we don't understand each other. The probelm is that the figure window is quadratic and I want a rectangular one, size one square to the right and one to the left. In each of these I want to put one subplot. I know how to resize them that they are quadratic. I repeat: I know how to change the aspect ratios of the subplots, but they should fit into the figure without leaving half the figure empty.

Comment: What about `pos = get(gcf,'Position'); set(gcf, 'Position', [0,0,pos(3),pos(3)/2])` *after* calling `axis("square")` on both your plots

Comment: @Dan thanks, that works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by quadratic you just mean a square shape then try calling `axis("square")` on each of your subplots and then to get rid of the excess on the figure window you can do this:

```
pos = get(gcf,'Position'); 
set(gcf, 'Position', [0,0,pos(3),pos(3)/2]); %// note the 'Position' argument takes a vector like [StartX, StartY, Width, Height)
```